# Knowing the laws of the universe but not its total state or ontology, what does philosophy have to say?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, knowledge, physicalism

Since GR but also in special relativity and QM we can have laws, yet never access to the total physical state of the universe at any time. And that the ontology of science, the physical, is changing and nebulous.

I'm interested to how this state of affairs fits within philosophy. Can we write down laws without knowing the totality?

For example: I may know the area of my backyard lawn and via Wikipedia, the densest grass per area species. With very little extra knowledge, I can write down a law that there will be at maximum X blades of grass in my lawn. But a new species with denser blades may evolve and its spores may travel into my lawn. Since I don't know the total physical arrangements possible yet, I shouldn't have written down my law. Are our physical laws "sophisticated" enough to prove no physical arrangements can violate our laws?

Then also, do we have to have the base ontology (e.g. an ontology of chemistry in the lawn example instead of current species) to be certain of our laws? What am I supposed to do until we have that base ontology? Since "physical" is always changing (i.e. the main scientific ontology), am I justified in saying the possibilities are as ungrounded as the term physical? (Ungrounded as QFT which has highly contested ontologies, and the gap between physical and mental).

How promiscuous can I be if I apply the lawn example to science. Can I doubt every scientific claim?

Comment: Your question has a couple of moving parts. One is related to the question of what commitments exactly one is making when one adopts a scientific theory.

Possible answers run the gamut from none at all, to only that the theory is empirically adequate (i.e. not contradicted by observation, so far), to belief that the theory's various entities all really exist (whatever that means) and stand in relation to one another the way the theory implies and so on. Some such commitments are ontological and others are not.

Comment: @thefringthing I guess I just made a worse version of Plato's Cave then. Does anyone talk about Plato's Cave together with modern physics?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that most of the philosophy of science from Duhem onward is about these kinds of considerations. Godfrey-Smith's popular textbook "Theory and Reality" is a good starting point.

Comment: To make predictions you need the initial state in addition to causal laws, formulated in the same language as the laws. That language may or may not reflect "base ontology", it can just describe useful fictions. So what you need for your grass is to fully know the "total" initial state of the universe, which, together with the laws, should, theoretically, allow you to predict evolution as well. And no, that is not humanly possible, although we can  approximate it. But even if it was that would still not assure you of knowing "base ontology". So it is irrelevant, accuracy of predictions is.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks that helps a lot.